# Dynamically add len method?

Tags: python, reflection

How do I add `__len__(...)` to an existing object in a way that `len(...)` likes?

The use case is remembering the length of a generator after its first iteration in a way that does not require writing/changing code in between the sites of the iterations.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def generator2iterator(generator):
    class Iterator(object):
        def __iter__(self):
            i = 0
            for e in generator():
                i += 1
                yield e
            #self.__len__ = types.MethodType(lambda self: i, self)
            self.__len__ = (lambda self: i).__get__(self)
    return Iterator()

def test_generator():
    yield 3

iterator = generator2iterator(test_generator)

print(list(iterator))
# [3]

print(iterator.__len__())
# 1

print(len(iterator))
# TypeError: object of type 'Foo' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an attribute that holds the length and return that for `__len__`.

```
def generator2iterator(generator, length=None):
    class Iterator(object):
        def __iter__(self):
            for i, e in enumerate(generator(), 1):
                self._len = i
                yield e
            #self.__len__ = types.MethodType(lambda self: i, self)

        def __len__(self):
            if not hasattr(self, '_len'):
                raise TypeError("object of type 'Iterator' has no defined len() yet.")
            return self._len
    return Iterator()

# examples:
## define a generator with 10 elements
def g():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

# pass it to the iterator
it = generator2iterator(g)

# check len
len(it)
TypeError: object of type 'Iterator' has no defined len() yet.

# run the iterator
for _ in it:
    pass

# check the length
len(it)
# returns:
10
```

Comment: Then there would be a time for which `len(it)` gives the wrong answer.

Comment: You can't always determine the length of a generator ahead of time.  Can you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: I would like `__len__` to not be defined (calls to `len` fail, as they should) until the first iteration, after which we know the length of the generator--so (possibly) dynamically adding the method.

Comment: oh!  in that case, remove the definition of `__init__` and raise an error.  see my update